# Redux redirect using redux-thunk

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Hey guys I have a function as so:

```
function dispatchSignup(username, password) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    const newUser = {username: username, password: password}
    axios.post('/signup', newUser).then(() => {
      return dispatch(signupAction)
    }).then(() => {
      return dispatch(push('/'))
    }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)})  
  }
}
```

This function is first sending a request to my server to signup. If successful, '.then' runs and dispatches a signupAction. I then call another '.then' after this, which should only run after this signupAction has been dispatched, which will redirect the user to '/' aka. my home page. The problem I'm having, is that yes they signup, and the url pushed works, however it's not actually rendering the component at '/'. What is happening here? It's as if they're blocking one another, although I'm not really sure. Redux-thunk is async I thought, so the second action I call won't be dispatched until the first has successfully dispatched.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I then call another '.then' after this, which should only run after this signupAction has been dispatched

This assumption is incorrect. The [`dispatch`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) function returns the action being dispatched, not a `Promise`. Assuming `signupAction` is also using redux-thunk (returning an action), then that would explain why your call to `push('/')` is happening immediately and not waiting for your signup process to be complete.